# Não consigo fazer $http.post no Angular, e não me é retornado nenhum erro

Tags: angularjs

Apesar de não retornar erro, o POST parece não estar funcionando.

Meu código:

```
// ADICIONA contato AO VETOR contatos
    $scope.adicionarContato = function(contato) {
      contato.data = new Date();
      // REALIZA POST EM contatos, PASSANDO contato COMO OBJETO
      $http.post("http://localhost:80/contatos", contato).then( function (successCallback) {
        delete $scope.contato; //o contato será deletado
        $scope.contatoForm.$setPristine();
        carregarContatos(); //recarrega os contatos
      }, function (errorCallback) {
        $scope.message = "Erro ao postar " + errorCallback.data;
      });
    };
```

Fazendo debug no navegador parece que está tudo ok com o POST, porém nenhum dado é passado para o arquivo no localhost.

Comment: Olha a requisição pelo navegador e vê se os dados estão sendo enviados mesmo.

Comment: O 'status code' está dando OK. Nos parâmetros o objeto a ser passado está correto, porém no response o JSON retornado não contém o objeto.

Comment: Quem é `carregarContatos();`? O retorno do POST não está sendo interpretado - e provavelmente está sendo perdido.

Comment: @SnailGalford Se a resposta não é a esperada pode ser um erro no _back-end_, não?

Comment: @LINQ no _back-end_ é um simples servidor local do apache com arquivos estátitos `.json`

Comment: @SnailGalford E você está tentando fazer um POST para um arquivo JSON?

Comment: @LINQ então, não manjo de _back-end_. Qual seria a maneira correta? Estava seguindo um tutorial de Angular porém essa parte não foi muito especificada. Desculpe caso seja algo muito leigo.

Comment: Bem, é que não faz muito sentido fazer um POST para um arquivo JSON. Seria necessário uma aplicação _backend_ para receber e interpretar a requisição.

Comment: Vou pesquisar mais sobre então... Eu estava acostumado com Java e MySQL server. Parece que web é um pouco diferente.